# how to get different background color for Launchscreen.storyboard for diff builds in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, launch-screen

Basically there is one Launchscreen.storyboard in iOS and in the project I'm working on i have various environments as in Local, Development, Production.

Can i have three different background colors for the respective builds on the same launchscreen? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is adding a Run-Script phase to the Build Phases section.
The script should look at the environment variables in order to determine what the current environment is, and replace the relevant XML element inside the storyboard file.

Answer (score 0):

The Launch Screen is set by target not the schemas so you can't do this for the same `launchScreen.xib` file.

Maybe a solution would be to make a viewcontroller for the launch screen, but that's not possible either. Even if possible, The launch screen appears instantly when your app starts up. So writing some code in launchScreen's viewcontroller would be pointless